# Unexpected result array of characters C

Tags: arrays, c

The objective of the exercise is to get the index of the first character of the array that is equal with the character I give as an argument. The problem is that always give me the number `-256` instead of the index.

I have tried to change the `while` conditions and the `%` of printf and anything make the difference. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIM 80

int main() {
    char argumento;
    char linea[DIM];
    int res = -1;
    printf("Ponga el caracter argumento\n");
    scanf("%s", &argumento);
    printf("ponga la cadena:\n");
    scanf("%s", linea);

    int i = 0;

    while (linea[i] != '\0' && res == -1) {
        if (linea[i] == argumento) {
            res = i;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    printf("El primer caracter que coincide es de indice: %d", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &argumento);` The variable `argumento` is a *single* character, and yet you attempt to read a null-terminated string into it. If you want to read a single character use `scanf(" %c", &argumento);` (note leading space and the `%c` format specifier).

Comment: Insider trick: Your `while()` loop could be replaced with a call to `strchr()`, a standard C library function. Look into it, and write less code...

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behavior.

`scanf("%s", &argumento)` will write beyond the end of the variable `argumento`, possibly corrupting other variables, such as `res`. The observed behavior is consistent with `scanf()` writing a null byte at the address of `res`, changing its initialized value from `-1` to `-256`, causing the loop to exit immediately and the output you observe.

The behavior is undefined, anything else could happen, you should use `%c` to read a byte from `stdin`, but beware to ignore pending white space with a space in front of `%c` if you read other input using `scanf()`. Also pass the maximum number of characters to store to the destination arrays for `%s` to avoid another buffer overflow: use `%79s` in your case. And always test the return value of `scanf`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char argumento;
    char linea[80];

    printf("Ponga el caracter argumento\n");
    if (scanf(" %c", &argumento) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("ponga la cadena:\n");
    if (scanf("%79s", linea) != 1)
        return 1;

    int res = -1;
    int i = 0;
    while (linea[i] != '\0') {
        if (linea[i] == argumento) {
            res = i;
            break;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    printf("El primer caracter que coincide es de indice: %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

`scanf()` is very tricky and error prone, it is recommended to use `fgets()` instead to read a line of input from `stdin` and parse the contents appropriately:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char linea[80];

    printf("Ponga el caracter argumento\n");
    if (!fgets(linea, sizeof linea, stdin))
        return 1;

    char argumento = linea[0];

    printf("ponga la cadena:\n");
    if (!fgets(linea, sizeof linea, stdin))
        return 1;

    int res = -1;
    for (int i = 0; linea[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (linea[i] == argumento) {
            res = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("El primer caracter que coincide es de indice: %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```